# IEqualityComparer string value within object

Tags: c#, iequalitycomparer

I quite possibly am doing this the wrong way but;

I have a list of objects in LINQ;

```
MyObj
  string name
  string somethingElse

List<MyObj> myObjects;
```

Now I'm trying to see if any object in that list has a string value;

So I have;

```
if (Model.myObjects.Contains("thisobject", new MyObjComparer()))
{
}
```

In the comparer I have;

```
public class MyObjComparer: IEqualityComparer<MyObj>
{
    public bool Equals(string containsString, MyObj obj)
    {
        return obj.name == containsString;
    }
}
```

How can I use a comparer to check against a string value in an objects field?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An easier method is to do this:

```
if (Model.myObjects.Any(o => o.name == "thisobject"))
{
}
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot about the overload of `Any` that takes a predicate delegate. +1 for that!

Comment: Thanks for thisand for @Harry for pointing out that I'm not using comparer corrently.

Answer (score 2):

You can use FindAll method as follows:

```
foreach(var item in Model.myObjects.FindAll(x=>x.Contains("thisobject")))
{
 //Do your stuff with item  
}
```

Comment: I really only want to check to see if there is a single item in the list that matches.  I know I can do a count but would like to use the comparer

Answer (score 2):

The equality comparer is only good to tell if two objects of the same type are equal. I don't know your use-case, but could you simply do something like

```
if (Model.myObjects.Where(x => x.name == "thisobject").Any())
{ 
    // Do something
}
```